# Is there a way to mark certain file types as binary for magit, so that they are not diffed?

Tags: magit

Magit sometimes becomes very slow, when it thinks that certain large files should be diffed.  Examples for this are SVG graphics or SQL dumps (technically seen as text files).  The files are small enough that they should be controlled by git, but seemingly too large (and with very long lines) for magit to display.

Is there a way to tell magit not to create the diff for certain file types?  Maybe something like a blacklist?

Comment: Binary for Magit *only*?  You still need other git front-ends to provide diffs?

Comment: Good point, it will mostly be the same wanted behavior for all front-ends. Still being able to switch it on/off for a specific magit diff invocation would be nice.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done for a whole repository with a `.gitattributes` file (or globally with `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/attributes`):

```
# content of .gitattributes

*.svg   -diff
*.sql   -diff
```

---

Kudos to [@phils](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/454/phils) for the comment which led me to write this answer.